# How to alter the index in my table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have one sql query is working fine like when `trip_member` table name

suppose `trip_member` total 20 records is there means my SQL query executing perfectly and return the response also perfectly.

**My QUERY**

```
SELECT tm.empId, tm.pickupTime, tm.dropTime, td.companyId, td.tripId, td.startTime, td.endTime, td.tripDate, td.forceEndStatus, td.tripStatus, c.shiftTiming, c.routeId, c.cabId,(select count('*') from trip_member as m WHERE m.tripId=td.tripId and m.empPresentStatus = '1') as absentcount,(select count('*') from trip_member as m WHERE m.tripId=td.tripId and m.empPresentStatus = '0') as presentcount,(select count('*') from trip_member as m WHERE m.tripId=td.tripId and m.pickupotpStatus = '1') as pickupcount
FROM trip_member tm
LEFT JOIN trip_details td ON tm.`tripId` = td.`tripId` 
INNER JOIN cab_allocation c ON c.`allocationId` = td.`allocationId` WHERE c.companyId = '1' 
ORDER BY td.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

But my `trip_member` table I have 20k records, suppose I am executing query now means I am getting error like this

> #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I think I have to use index in my table but I don't know how to use index and also which fields I have use index, if any one know means please update your `sql alter query in index`

Comment: "How to alter the index in my table" -> https://www.google.nl/search?q=How+to+alter+the+index+in+my+table

Comment: For your sake and ours format your query so the dependent subqueries are visible without scrolling. Please [edit] your post. And, read this paying special attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: Questions about performance should include `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` outputs and `EXPLAIN [query]` output.

Comment: Why do you think you need an index to correct the `lost connection` error? According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html), there are three likely causes: network connectivity trouble, large amount of data being sent (millions of rows, not 20k) and `connect_timeout` being set to a few seconds. Did you investigate these causes?

Comment: Setting of indexes is unrelated to losing the network connection during the query. Are you trying to say your query is taking a very long time?